# Qt c++ timing issue

Tags: c++, qt, loops, timing

In my program I'm currently trying to achieve a live update of registers of a chip. This live update must be at certain intervals, 60hz and 120hz are common but if possible 200hz would be even better.

Anyway, I want to optimise my loops since speed is critical. To see where the slow parts are I use QElapsedTimer to measure elapsed nanoseconds. I'm currently stuck with, what it seems, massive overhead of for/while loops in Qt.

Code:

```
QElapsedTimer outsideloop;
QElapsedTimer insideloop;
int totalinside = 0;

outsideloop.start();

while(x<reg.size())
{
  insideloop.start();
  //get registers from chip
  //process register values
  x++;
  totalinside+= insideloop.nsecsElapsed();
}

qDebug()<<"Time elapsed Outside:"<<outsideloop.nsecsElapsed();<<"inside:"<<totalinside;
```

Now, the time of only "inside" the loop is often about 4-5 milliseconds less than the time measured "outside" the loop. To give you an example, the "inside" often measures around 5ms but the outside often measures about 10ms. Sometimes the difference is smaller (1ms) and sometimes much bigger (15-30ms). This difference is also there when I use a for loop.

Also, I measured the time it take to go into and go out of the loop like so:

```
nstimer.start();
while(x<reg.size())
{
  qDebug()<<"Time to get into loop"<<nstimer.nsecsElapsed();
  nstimer.start();
}
qDebug()<<"Time to get out of loop"<<nstimer.nsecsElapsed();
```

This takes about 0.005ms each on my system so not really relevant.

I'm not sure what is causing this since it's not really a steady delay. 
I would like to have everything as fast as possible and thus eliminate that extra time difference which is giving me troubles.

Apologies for my inexperience if I missed the obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to help when your example isn't complete.  For instance, without knowing the type of `reg`, we don't know how slow `reg.size()` is going to be.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to share your compilation command, so we can see that you used `-O3` rather than just assuming you didn't forget that...

Comment: Note that on most desktop OS's, you're not going to get reliable hard-real time behavior; "execution gaps" of 10-20 milliseconds are common (they happen when the OS runs some other task instead of your own task, for a while), and if the computer is under load, the gaps could be much longer than that.  If you need real-time behavior (and I agree with Kuba's answer below, it sounds like you don't) then you would need to run on a hard-real time OS.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point in doing the updates any faster than the screen update rate. If you need to be tied to screen update rate, you'll have to implement your UI using OpenGL or D3D and fetch new data from the chip after each vsync.

But I question the need for any of that. There will be a multitude of values, and the human who consumes this can't do much with them at such a fast update rate anyway. Remember that humans take about 200ms to process a text/numerical value. If you present a non-text/non-numerical display, it's better but I doubt it will make any difference in practice. You're not designing a game.

Most likely, the communications channel between your UI and the chip you're interfacing with has limited bandwidth and/or decent latency, so if you have an object in one thread that continuously reads data from the chip and emits the new values, and the UI object consuming these, it'll work just fine without need for timers. You'd use the properties of the communication system to ensure proper timing by leveraging the inherent latencies and bandwidth limits to derive a time base.

Going back to your question itself: the loop is a C++ loop. Its performance is tied to what you're doing in the loop, and to the performance of the scheduler on the platform you run this code on. Nothing to do with Qt itself.